# Why would AJAX cause a PHP session crash?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've got a headache... I've used this line of code many times before whether in `onkeyup` situations or otherwise. Ive had the issue before with `onkeyup` calls but solved that with a `KeyUpDelay(function)`.

Using this line of code to search for duplicates....

```
if (cat == 'cur') {

    $.post('searchDBajax.php',{rmDocDup: ""+type+"", rmid: ""+<? echo $row['id']; ?>+""}, function(data){
        if(data.length >0){
            alert("f*ck");
        }
    });

}
```

The PHP side...

```
if(isset($_POST['rmDocDup'])) {
    $type = $_POST['rmDocDup'];
    $rmid = $_POST['rmid'];
    $query = $db2->query("SELECT * FROM rmDocs WHERE rmid='$rmid' AND cat='cur' AND type='$type'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) != 0 ) {
        echo "1";
    }
}
```

This causes the PHP session to crash.

The code is almost identical to other events. The only difference is this is not called with a `onkeyup` event.

Searching I have found nothing useful.

Any ideas?

Comment: What this actually means `This causes the PHP session to crash`?I don't see any session related code in your post?

Comment: There is nothing which could cause session crash in that code. There has to be something else.

Comment: This is behind a login session.... Once this code executes the user is logged out. No logs on the server (apache or php) to indicate why.

Comment: If `cat != 'cur'` there is no session crash. It's this line of code that triggers the session crash.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue!

The PHP file searchDBajax.php running the process has `require(includes/config.inc.php);`. The config file calls a functions.inc.php file. Within that is the session function. The session function had `session_regenerate_id(true);`. This was changing the session info with the AJAX request.

AJAX is not sending headers.

I changed the sessions function to `if (headers_sent()) {session_regenerate_id(true);}` and all is well.

Comment: headers_sent() referers to server